# Is there a way to clear the space before and after the data that Vue binds?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, ionic-framework

[image: here is the screenshot]

I'm using Vue, and there's a space on the screen after the binding.
Vanilla JavaScript, like the trim() function of pure JavaScript, is there a way to erase the front and rear margins?

I'll show you the code of the binding process.
[image: this image is binding code]

Comment: not clear what do you want to do. Please share more details such as code, screenshot

Comment: Try `<p>{{ yourValue.trim() }}</p>`. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/trim.

Comment: @NileshPatel Literally there's a space before and after the text in that " 1 ".
I want to look like "1". But it's " 1 " now.

Comment: Unfortunately, that is number type in Vue and cannot use trim() function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are experiencing is basic DOM interpretation.
When you have a tag spanning multiple line, the browser will render a word space before any text.

This is a good thing most of the times, if you for example have `<span>` tags in your text, you probably want a space before it.

So i think the solution you are looking for, is simply: Make it 1 line

```html
<!-- This will have spaces -->
<div>
  1
</div>

<!-- This will not have spaces -->
<div>2</div>
```

Comment: Hey!!! You genius!!! Thanks a lot. I didn't even think about it.

Comment: @jungjuyoung No problem! 